# Define proper group action on a square

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Obviously one can let the dihedral group of order 8 act on a square. How do I define this action mathematically correct? Since the dihedral group leaves the square invariant and just permutes the corners, must I take the set $M=\{(a,b,c,d)\mid 1\leq a,b,c,d\leq4\}$? And then i.e. for the rotation $r\star (1,2,3,4)=(4,1,2,3)$?

Comment: Your set $M$ has $256$ elements and many orbits. Why would you consider such a set? The standard interpretation of the action is on the vertex set, which has $4$ elements. Another possible interpretation of the action is a group of eight isometries (in particular, linear operators) of $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @anon Your comment of "why would you consider such a set" sounds needlessly dismissive - the OPs idea is actually quite a natural way to think of the action. The element $(4, 1, 2, 3)$ corresponds to the permutation $(4, 1)(1, 2)(2, 3)(3, 4)$ naturally; the OPs interpretation corresponds to the "standard" idea of a Cartesian product, while the permutation interpretation corresponds to thinking of a Cartesian product using an index set ($4\mapsto 1, 1\mapsto 2, 2\mapsto 3, 3\mapsto 4$).

Comment: @user1729 What permutation does $(1,1,1,1)$ correspond to?

Comment: @anon That is not a permutation. $(a, b, c, d)$ corresponds to a permutation if and only if the numbers $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are pairwise distinct.

Comment: @user1729 Yes, and $(1,1,1,1)$ is part of OP's set, so I'm not sure why you're talking about $4$-tuples being interpreted as permutations in one-line notation unless for some reason you're only focusing on three orbits of $D_4$'s action on $\{1,2,3,4\}^4$. Even in one of these three orbits (cosets of $D_4$ in $S_4$), the regular action of $D_4$ does not match the action of $D_4$ on the square - which should be interpreted as a set of four vertices, or as a set of points in the plane stabilized by a group of isometries - which is what OP is *trying* to do, no?

Comment: @anon Okay, I think I see your point. Yes, $(1, 1, 1, 1)$ is part of the OPs set, but one can ignore it and assume it is fixed. This is what I am doing (and, rightly or wrongly, I presumed that this is what the OP is doing). However, if you nitpick about this then you would have to nitpick about this group acting on the set with $5$ elements! I am merely trying to say that the OPs interpretation is natural, and not weird as you are suggesting.

Comment: @user1729 It's natural in the sense it's good that someone thought of $G$ acting on $X^n$ when $G$ acts on $X$, because induced actions are cool and interesting things. However, rereading the first two sentences in the OP, it's *not* natural in the sense that OP is trying to understand the action of  $D_4$ on the square, which does not match the action of $D_4$ on the OP's set $M$ - it is *mathematically incorrect* for that purpose

Comment: @anon I disagree - it is mathematically correct! It is not $X^n$ they are considering, but rather $X^4$. This $4$ is important. Their thought is entirely analogous to the idea that the Caresian product $X^4$ is the set of functions $\{f: \{1, 2, 3, 4\}\rightarrow X\}$.

Comment: @user1729 It doesn't matter what the exponent is. If they're trying to understand the action of $G$ on $X$, and they come up with the action on $X^n$ instead, they've got the wrong set. To reiterate, *again*, as OP explicitly stated, OP is trying to understand the action of $D_4$ on the square, which means not the regular action of $D_4$ on itself, or the action on the set of necklaces with distinct colored beads, etc. Once someone is able to understand what a group $G$ is *originally* defined to act on, then they can study induced actions on other associated structures.

Comment: If OP had instead said, "I am trying to understand the action of $D_4$ on itself as described by Cayley's Theorem," then the regular action of $D_4$ on itself (interpreted as a *proper* subset of $\{1,2,3,4\}^4$) would be correct. But OP explicitly asked to find how to define the action on the *square*, and explicitly mentioned how $D_4$ permutes the four corners in the lead up to defining $M$.

Comment: @anon Yes, sure, but the OP has encoded a square in a very specific, and quite natural, way .

Comment: @user1729 OP has *not* encoded a square though. The standard action of $D_4$ on a square (the set of four vertices) does *not* match the regular action of $D_4$ on itself. I have said this *multiple times* now. I suspect you are not reading any of my responses, so I suppose this non-discussion is over.

Answer (score 1):

A group action is merely a group homomorphism from a group $G$ to a subgroup of $\text{Sym}(X) \cong S_{|X|}$. It appears you want a *monomorphism*; that is, essentially "another way of describing $G$".

Since $|D_4| = 8$, to obtain such a monomorphism, we require $|X| > 3$. So expressing $D_4$ is a permutation of "$4$ somethings" is going to be optimal. What (symmetric) aspects of a square come in fours?

To understand more fully what I am getting at, note that the square has two diagonals, and that $D_4$ can act on these diagonals (how?). If we see $D_4$ as a subgroup of $S_4$, what are your conclusions regarding $D_4 \cap A_4$?

One of the comments suggest you might see $D_4$ as a subgroup of $\text{GL}_2(\Bbb R)$. To get you started how does:

$\rho = \begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$

act on the set $X = \{(1,0), (0,1), (-1,0), (0,-1)\}$?